# Toggle two checkboxes with one click and without js

Tags: html, checkbox, cross-browser

Is there a way to toggle two *combined* checkboxes with one click?

I have a small calander where I want to select weeks with checkboxes. One week can be in two month so I have two checkboxes for the same week. How can I combine them safe?

I'm using this abstract HTML:

```
<label for="aa"><input type="checkbox" id="bb" /></label><br />
<label for="bb"><input type="checkbox" id="aa" /></label>
```

See my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeF4f/5) for a full example.

This works fine in Firefox (exept you make a double click) in the IE9 is just the checkbox toggled where you click on.

**Please don't suggest to use JavaScript. I know that this would be very simple.**

Comment: Don't think that's valid HTML, you're asking if Firefox and IE9 would interpret bad markup in the same way and they don't appear to in this case.  Either way, you shouldn't depend on bad code.

Comment: For valid mark-up, I think you would have to (unfortunately) use... JavaScript. Sorry for mentioning JavaScript.

Comment: The output is valid `html` I think I'm just trying to to something which is not defined in any standard. I mean the click is blubbered (I guess that the right word) to the lable tag which calls a click event on the second checkbox. While the checkbox in the IE seems to consume the click event.

Comment: The W3C (organisation that sets web standards, e.g. made HTML) validator says that that markup is incorrect. See http://validator.w3.org.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff my output is valid see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeF4f/5/) and my [w3c result](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2FBeF4f%2F5%2Fshow%2F).

Comment: @bdares see my updated example there are no html errors. The errors you may saw seems to be related with some strange html 5 conditions.

Comment: Ah, I see now. XHTML allows this, but HTML5 does not. If you want a future-proof site, use HTML5...

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff do you know how to avoid this error in HTML5? I don't understand that error.

Comment: The error means that you cannot enclose a checkbox in a label that is '`for`' another element. This must be new in HTML5, and the only way to avoid it is to use JavaScript to check the boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about only having one checkbox? I mean, there's only one week, although it spans months it isn't two entire weeks! Consider your design, i.e. Week Ending 4/5/2012 is a week ending in May, sure it starts in April but if you're going to put your weeks in a bag, do it by something definitive if you can.

Comment: How should I decide if a day is in the actual month or in the last or next one. I think that would preduce uggly results.

Comment: Without seeing what you're trying to acheive in more detail, I'm afraid I can't answer. Feel free to post a jsfiddle (yes, I know you're not using javascript, but it's good for HTML/CSS too) or test page etc.

Comment: Here is my [updated jsfiddle](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2FBeF4f%2F5%2Fshow%2F).

Comment: Ok, I see what you're trying to achieve now, it's somewhat like the Outlook calendar. I'd strongly suggest JavaScript if you want to make it reliable.