# Is it possible to toggle two CSS `:checked` pseudo-classes with one click?

Tags: css

Please note that [I am aware of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829768/toggle-two-checkboxes-with-one-click-and-without-js) but I am looking for specifically a technical answer.

As a CSS challenge to myself I'm trying to create a fancy `select` box using only CSS. Using a variety of fancy techniques that [I've learned recently](http://modernweb.com/2014/07/30/5-things-wont-believe-built-css/), I've gotten pretty far.

[Codepen Here](http://codepen.io/togakangaroo/pen/mFqDA?editors=110)

- It looks good
- Is fully style-able,
- It opens up in a list on click (using a hidden checkbox and a `:checked+label` selector)
- Allows placeholder text (using `:checked` and a negative margin-top)
- Allows selection (using a nested radio button list)
- And displays value properly when selected and collapsed (using `:checked` and `position: absolute`)
- It will even bind javascript correctly

This is using a structure similar to

```
input[type=checkbox]#selector
label[for=selector]
    ul
        li.item1
            input[type=radio]#item1
            label[for=item1] The First Item
```

I have just one problem left, once expanded, closing the menu on click doesn't work properly. A normal selectbox will close when clicking on an item. Mine won't until you click near the border of the selectbox.

[image: Closed CSSelectbox]

[image: Open CSSelectoox]

That is because the user is clicking on the inner input which won't toggle the `:checked` state of the parent label, they need to click around the input to close the selectbox.

Is there any way to make both the radio button state *and* the parent state toggle at the same time?

Comment: *"...near a border of an item"* and also directly on the flag image (FF)

Comment: The way that I see it, is that the `options` label overlap the `country-selector` label. The options label prevent the country-selector label from triggering. I guess that's how the browsers process it and there isn't a way around (except for JS)...

Comment: @LinkinTED See I was thinking of doing something where we use css transitions to occillate display/hide a transparent element that would cover the whole thing. My thought then was that I might be able to capture click on both but no deal.

Comment: You should not use block elements inside inline elements, this creates a lot of issues on different browsers, lik ethte one you are having right now, I have been creating fancy form elements for months and I know what you are dealing with, I know how to solve your problem, but some html and css modification most be applied, please let me know if you want to know how, I will be willing to explain you and show you, no prob! ^_^

Comment: Yes please @Allan. This is more of a personal CSS project so I'm still interested.

Comment: OK, I will share what I know and expertise with you. but not right now, I will when Im not as busy as now, that works for you?

Comment: Sure. I would love a working example. What's the basic idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible you might be overcomplicating this a bit.

Why not just change your `.country-selector` checkbox into a radio button in the same group?  Then it has exactly the behavior you're looking for without making it a situation that requires lots of workaround.  The only concern would be providing an empty value for if the user were to submit while the box is still open, but that's a concern with your existing implementation anyhow.

## [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Josh-Burgess/pen/myoEzQ)

**Jade**

```
input#country-selector(type='radio', name="country")
```

**SCSS**

```
&>[type=checkbox]
```

*becomes*

```
&>[type=radio]
```

I made a few styling changes to the pen as well to bring it inline with more traditional select dropdowns.

Very interesting idea.  Kudos on that.

Comment: Holy crap, you're right. That works great! This might need to get submitted to html5weekly...

Comment: Go for it.  I've always done similar things for toggle switches, never really thought to extend it to select options, though.  The beauty of this is that it's functionally _very_ similar to how a `select` control would work anyhow.  Ease of re-use would be high, and the styling possibilities essentially make it the mythical style-accessible select drop down.  Again, kudos.  Nicely done.

Comment: i like the idea because you keep thing simple +1, but i want to point out that there are some validation errors in your code, corresponding to your abuse of label: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fs.codepen.io%2FJosh-Burgess%2Ffullembedgrid%2FmyoEzQ%3Ftype%3Dembed%26safe%3Dtrue%26_t%3D1427708476973&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @ChaosClown Why are we not allowed to nest block elements inside inline elements, but are allowed to set `display: block` on inline elements (and vice versa)? Imho the rule to not nest block elements inside inline stops making sense as soon as you can set any element to be block-level or inline at will from CSS. Plus if you don't know in advance what the content will be, you can not use inline elements to contain it... which sort of pushes you towards using block level elements for everything.

Answer (score 3):

**edit**

internet explorer will treat a transparent element like event-pointer:none; there for one has to add a background-color + opacity:0. At least one can open it in internet explorer now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EargxL

**edit 2**

i finally found a way to support internet explorer, it looks a bit crappy atm, i will refactor it another day :p http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogmqpq

please note it will not work on most mobile devices as the dont implement :active pseudo-selector: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/mobile.html#link5

**original**

In short, it is almost impossible to trigger two toggles by checked selector on different inputs with only one click.

How ever one could use the :focus pseudo-selector in combination with :active.

```
<div class="dropDown">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="0"></div>
    <ul class="list" tabindex="0">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="myDropDown" value="someValue" checked="checked"/>
                <span>Item 1</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="myDropDown" value="someValue"/>
                <span>Item 2</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="myDropDown" value="someValue"/>
                <span>Item 3</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
input {
    display:none;
}
.dropDown {
    position:relative;
}
.dropDown .toggle {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    outline:none;
}
.dropDown > .toggle:focus {
    z-index:0;
}
.dropDown > .list {
    position:relative;
    outline:none;
}
.dropDown > .list:active {
    z-index:1;
}
.dropDown > .toggle:not(:focus) + .list:not(:active) input:not(:checked) + span {
    display:none;
}
```

live example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emxJWr

**note:**
this will not work in internet explorer because :active is not bubbling up, im open for any suggestions!

Comment: wow, pretty nice, I'm going to have to look into this but this seems by far the closest thing.

Answer (score 3):

**just for the curiosity of `pointer-events`**: a doubleclick on a `input:checked + label` will allow you here to close your fancy selector : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NPJaNa

```
.options {
      &>li{
        &:hover {
          background-color: blue;
        }
        input[name=country]:checked+label {
          position: static;
          pointer-events:none;}
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the z-index will allow the user to click on the label area which toggles your drop down.

See my updated codepen: 
        [codepen ex](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kKjCx)

```
  .country-selector {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:before {
    content: "▾";
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index:-1;
  }
```

Changed the .country-selector .options margin and took off the .country-selector padding-right.

Then changed the .country-selector:before to z-index of -1.

Not sure if this will work across all browsers/devices but does seem to work on FF and chrome (OS x).

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I don't get it, When I click on the country name it doesn't collapse therefore the parent checkbox toggle isn't triggered. Also just fyi, look you should look up the markdown syntax for links

Comment: He's using that to bypass SO's restrictions on posting links and not codes.

Answer (score 1):

There is validation error which prevents it to work correctly:

> The element label must not appear as a descendant of the label element.

If you put spans instead of inner labels, everything works fine.
You also have multiple input fields inside parent label, but this require bigger fix, since you need to trigger `country-selector` checkbox with it.

[Working pen.](http://codepen.io/easingthemes/pen/rEdGg)

Comment: But then the input element never gets selected. `span` doesn't support the `for` attribute. I agree that there isn't exactly proper validation but like I said, this is all an experiment.