# Drop down values are showing up in IE10. How to customize it

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using IE 10 browser. I have created one drop down menu with some values added to it. Code working fine in Chrome as my requirement but in IE10 drop down values are showing up. How to customize that to look like chrome. and selector(round marked in image) also not looking like the one looks in Chrome.

[image: Chrome view]

[image: IE10 view]

the above image shows the values in dropdown are showing up in IE10.Ignore any values mismatch inside both dropdowns(they are hardcoded).

Here is my code and both CSS and Jsp are in same file

```
File.jsp

           <div class="row">
             <div class="large-5 medium-8 small-12 columns"
                id="Area_dropdown_label">
              Area of Business 

                <select class="no-highlight"
                    id="Area_dropdown" name="Area"

                    <option value="select" selected="selected">Select</option>

                    <option value="Drive">Drive</option>
                    <option value="Front">Front</option>
                    <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
                    <option value="McCafe">McCafe</option>
                    <option value="Back">Back</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>

  .ie #Area_dropdown{
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 2.3125em;
  margin-bottom: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff0%, #f3f3f3 100%);
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

if my css code itself wrong then please suggest me to change. Any kind of suggestions/help are welcome and useful for me. Please comment for any clarification on this question.

Comment: Every browser renders/displays form elements on different way - with pure css, it is hard to get uniform look. You will need some javascript for it, but: http://aaronmbushnell.com/lets-stop-customizing-form-fields/

Comment: @nevermind – You could always go full CSS with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215192/is-it-possible-to-toggle-two-css-checked-pseudo-classes-with-one-click/29303287#29303287

Comment: @JoshBurgess, yes, but as i can see - ul/li structure is used here, instead regular select box? P.S. Basically, all js/jquery plug-ins does same thing, and then look can be consistent in all browsers.

Comment: @All.. Thanks for your suggestions..then I can not customize the way browser behaves ? I can not bring down the values showing up in IE?

Comment: @nevermind – Yup, but functionally it's the exact same as the select box. You're polling a named collection in a form with only one valid selection option.

Comment: @user3534759 – You can't customize the select box in any meaningful way, no.

Comment: @JoshBurgess.. I have seen in some application they have done it in both chrome and IE as well but why cant i do it? there must be a way if not meaningful also..Appreciate your suggestion

Comment: There are tons of javascript-based plugins out there that will do something similar, plus other non-javascript options like the one linked above.  However, none of these are `select` elements in the way you're hoping to use them.