# Dropdown looking a bit weird on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Hey I am using a `select` with `option` and the result isn't pretty at all on IE:
[image]

The arrows on the right doesn't look smooth at all. Is there anyway to change the default design of this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Each browser renders select dropdowns in their own way, if you want a uniform style the best option would be to fake a select dropdown using standard elements and Javascript. Alternatively, you could use a plugin such as [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Comment: On that note - I highly recommend [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) over select2 if you want your selects to be more akin to comboboxes. Both are great options though.

Comment: Might want to check out this implementation using only CSS, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215192/is-it-possible-to-toggle-two-css-checked-pseudo-classes-with-one-click/29303287